# elastic search suggester only spell check on single word not multi word

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search and try to use elastic search suggester, in multi search like `comercial manager` spell checker get my wrong word(`comercial`) but when search `comercial manger` elastic only correct (`manger`) and leave `comecial`

this is my result when search:

**SEARCH `comercial manager`=>**

`"simple_phrase": [
      {
        "text": "comercial manager",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 17,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "commercial manager",
            "highlighted": "<em>commercial</em> manager",
            "score": 0.1643392
          }
        ]
      }
    ]`

**And SEARCH `comercial manger`=>**

`"simple_phrase": [
      {
        "text": "comercial manger",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 16,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "commercial manger",
            "highlighted": "<em>commercial</em> manger",
            "score": 0.023379987
          }
        ]
      }
    ]`

**I want result like this=>**

`"simple_phrase": [
      {
        "text": "comercial manger",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 16,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "commercial manger",
            "highlighted": "<em>commercial manager</em>",
            "score": 0.023379987
          }
        ]
      }
    ]`

Comment: Can you post the query?